# Relative links in Express/Jade

Tags: express, pug

I'm trying to get my Jade template to write a hyperlink (`<a>`) relative to the current URL.

For example, my view is called from `http://localhost/cats` and it looks like this:

```
extends layout

block content
  a(href='fluffy') Fluffy
```

When the link is clicked, it takes me to `http://localhost/fluffy`, instead of `http://localhost/cats/fluffy`

Things I've tried:

- `a(href='./fluffly')`
- `a(href='\\fluffy')`
- `a(href='/fluffy')`

Just about the only thing that works is writing out the absolute path, like `a(href='cats/fluffy')`. Surely there's a better way to do it.

Comment: I can't reproduce it, so are you sure you're not opening `/cats`? Express, by default, doesn't care about trailing slashes and treats `/cats` and `/cats/` as being the same (so they will both trigger the same route).

Comment: Are you using the `<base>` tag? If yes, what's the value?

Comment: @robertklep I'm sure.
@gustavohenke I am not using the `<base>` tag.. perhaps I should.

In fact, I just checked the HTML output and it is appearing correctly as `<a href="fluffy">`. Unfortunately, when I click on it, it's still going to http://localhost/fluffy, even though the current page is http://localhost/cats

Comment: @Travis I hope that's a typo? `localhost/cats` (without trailing slash)

Comment: @robertklep Oops.. Do you want to add that as an answer and I'll accept it :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you already noticed yourself, when you open `/cats` it's to be expected that a relative link to `fluffy` would lead you to `/fluffy` :)

Bit of background: the default behavior of Express is to treat `/cats` and `/cats/` as the same, and both will trigger the same route.

You either have to take that into account when you create links (especially relative links), or tell Express to treat them as two separate routes:

```
app.enable('strict routing');

app.get('/cats/', function(req, res) {
  ...
});
```

This will match `/cats/`, but not `/cats`. Of course, when you leave off the trailing slash in the route definition, this behavior will be reversed.

Answer (score 2):

If you're using `gulp-jade`, add `gulp-data` to the mix and use this code:

```js
var jade = require('gulp-jade');
var data = require('gulp-data');

gulp.src('**/*.jade')
  .pipe(data(function (file) {
    var relativePath = file.history[0].replace(file.base, ''); //e.g. about/index.jade
    var depth = (relativePath.match(/\//g) || []).length; //e.g. 1
    var relativeRoot = new Array(depth + 1).join( '../' ); //e.g. ../
    return {
      relativeRoot: relativeRoot
    };
  }))
  .pipe(jade())
```

This will give you a `relativeRoot` in your `jade` templates that is essentially: `<nothing>` or `../` repeated as many times as the number of directories it's nested relative to the base folder.

Then, in your templates:

```js
link(rel='stylesheet', href= relativeRoot + 'assets/main.css')
```

I'm not entirely sure of where/how that `file.history` is generated, but in my case `[0]` pointed to the original filename (with its absolute path on the disk)

Comment: Clever!  Worked well for me.  I made sure to comment the heck out of this, though, as it's not an approach I would have expected, and the `relativeRoot` variable seems to come from nowhere, from the template's perspective.

Comment: For those who want _all_ their urls to be relative, even when depth = 0: `var relativeRoot = depth === 0 ? './' : new Array(depth + 1).join('../');`